# Can these similar methods be refactored to a single method?

Tags: vb.net, dry

My coding skill is somewhere between novice and expert. As with everyone, I am always trying to learn to code more simply and efficiently.  The DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle is driving this question.  I read a great many SO posts, and really wasn't able to glean an answer that resonated.

The application has 3 layers: UI, domain, storage. The storage layer has a class that works as a service to save program data to an SQL Server.  There are multiple classes that are somewhat similar but not completely similar.  The classes cascade like this:

```
Class Parent
  :
  Public Property Children as New List(Of ParentChild)
End Class

Class ParentChild
  :
  Public Property Children as New List(Of ParentGrandChild)
End Class

Class ParentGrandChild
  :
End Class
```

The CRUD methods for these classes look a lot alike, which caused me to wonder if they met the criteria for the DRY principle.  What follows is just the Update methods for 3 of the classes (there are actually a total of 5 classes that use this same type of method):

```
Public Overrides Sub ParentUpdate(Parent As Parent)
  Dim thisSqlParent = SqlContext.SqlParents.Find(Parent.ID)
  thisSqlParent.DomainToSqlParent(Parent)
  SqlContext.SaveChanges()
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub ChildUpdate(ParentChild As ParentChild)
  Dim thisSqlChild = SqlContext.SqlChildren.Find(ParentChild.ID)
  thisSqlChild.DomainToSqlChild(ParentChild)
  SqlContext.SaveChanges()
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub GrandchildUpdate(Grandchild As ParentGrandchild)
  Dim thisSqlGrandchild = SqlContext.SqlActivities.Find(Grandchild.ID)
  thisSqlGrandchild.DomainToSqlGrandchild(Grandchild)
  SqlContext.SaveChanges()
End Sub
```

Given there are 4 CRUD methods and I have 5 classes, that's a lot of pretty similar code.

There are several implied questions here.

1) **Is it even possible to refactor these somewhat similar methods**?  At my level of coding skill, I don't understand how it would be done because the code within each method above is making different calls with different classes; but then I'm not an expert coder which is why I'm asking.

2) **Given these methods are so short, does it make sense to refactor**?  From other SO posts it became clear that sometimes refactoring doesn't make sense because of the tradeoff in effort when the repeated code is so simple.

3) **But even if it doesn't make sense, if it is possible to refactor such code, how would that be done**?  If it's something I need to go study, please point me in the right direction.

Although this is vb.net, the languages seem similar enough that the suggested C# tag made sense.  I also wondered if this post is OK for SO because it is more general, or if I should post it on codereview.stackexchange.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this would be a more suitable question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can I move the post, or do I need to copy it over?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/how-do-i-move-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site

Comment: This is too broad for Stack Overflow. You should not include [tag:c#] for a question with no C#. You might be able to improve the question so that it would be appropriate on codereview.stackexchange.com, but note that it's not currently in a state where I'd expect that community to receive this well. Read through their own Tour and asking guidelines.

Comment: Understood the question doesn't work well here on SO.  I did read their tour and it seemed like my post met their requests.  If you could comment in general what I need to change, I can try to do that.  I'll wait for your response for a few moments, and then ask the moderator to move the question. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Some combination of generics, possibly interfaces, and the "curiously recurring template pattern" would probably allow you to refactor the above into a single routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a base class (e.g. `Person`) with the common code. Each of your other classes then implements this. Noting that VB does not do multiple inheritance.

Comment: I did consider that design but for reasons that don't make sense to go into on this post, decided to go a different way.  But I may end up going back to your idea later.  My question was more about whether or not it's even possible the methods listed can be combined.  I figured not, but just because I don't know how to do it doesn't mean it can't be done.  We can only learn by asking.

Comment: Creating a common base class only works if all subclasses really are base classes (e.g. 'Person`) always and forever. Since @AJD's classes have different members I suspect this is not true.

Comment: @DourHighArch - not clear what you are driving at. The OP notes that at least the CRUD are the same in all the classes, so a base class makes good sense here. @Craig's comment on the OP makes sense as well (can define properties: `Child` is `Grandchild` if `Parent` has `Parent` (who is then `Grandparent`)